# Device login detection with node.js and react.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, device, tracking

I need to restrict users to login from multiple devices. I'm using react.js at the frontend and node.js as the backend. Which is the most reasonable way to handle this task?

Answer (score 0):

I can not imagine how you can identify user browser 100 %. Cookies are browser based,so that could not solve the problem. Try Matteo Collina's [pino](https://github.com/pinojs/pino) logger, I think that it has many options.so you can choose most suitable for your task.
For example,this simple code

```
const express = require('express');
const pino = require('pino');
const expressPino = require('express-pino-logger');
 
const logger = pino({ level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'info' });
const expressLogger = expressPino({ logger });
 
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();
 
app.use(expressLogger);
 
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 logger.debug('Calling res.send');
 res.send('Hello World');
});
 
app.listen(PORT, () => {
 logger.info('Server running on port %d', PORT);
});
```

would show

```
"level":30,"time":1613817528986,"pid":17345,"hostname":"jholmes","msg":"Server running on port 3000"
```

You can pick IP,but would dynamic Id's you can not point pot to single user.
React also has plenty libraries for auth(ajv).